# Why reactjs doesnot render objects whose variable name starts with small letter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started work with facebook's library for virtual DOM binding "ReactJS" along with JSXTransformer. I'm following small simple getting started tutorials from http://ryanclark.me/getting-started-with-react/ .

I wrote a simple code to render a div on my page within body tag having message "Hello world" but React didn't render it nor it gave any error.
my code is following.

```
<script type="text/jsx">
    var customMessage = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return <div>Hello World</div>;
        }       
    });
    React.render(<customMessage />,document.body);
</script>
```

After a hard struggle of 1 hour I came to know that it is due to my variable name '**c**ustomMessage'. when I changed it to **C**ustomMessage (**starting with capital 'C'**) it worked fine. Just want to know is there any specific reason for why variable names starting with small letter is not allowed here while we can easily use them in javascript.I haven't found it (or may be I missed) in tuturials and online documentation.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Comment: Thanks @TahirAhmed for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React recognizes components by capital letters. If it does not start with a capital one, it assumes that it's a regular HTML tag.

Comment: checking the debugger he should have noticed this. I remeber there is an explicit error raised for this issue

Comment: @MaxBumaye There is no error at all in the debugger (I'm using chrome).

Comment: @slomek you said "it assumes that it's a regular HTML tag" ? can we pass regular HTML tag too in the React.render() callback ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @slomek